# Pass a value from WinForm to Crystal Report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I used this code to pass a value from `DatagridviewCell` to Crystal Report

FormulaField:

```
CrystalReport6 objRpt6 = new CrystalReport6();

for (int i = 0; i < statistiqueDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
{
    objRpt6.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["CodeBonLivraison11"].Text =
        "'" + statistiqueDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() +  "'";
}
```

But I get this error message:

> Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Although the field name is correct but I get this error message, how to solve this?

Comment: Error corresponds to wrong parameter. Could you verify that parameter names are the same in report and code?

Comment: Agreed - sounds like the formula field name `CodeBonLivraison11*` is wrong. Looking at it, is that asterisk meant to be on the end of that string?

Comment: No the name is correct i removed the asterisk and the same error appear

Comment: When you tested it, did you remember to remove the asterisk from the Formula field name as well? Just checking they match, and that astisk isn't some kind of reserve character or anything

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a Formula or would a parameter be better? A parameter can be fed using: 
mrptDoc.SetParameterValue("PopulationThreshold", 5000000)

For more details, check http://emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/09/Feeding-Crystal-Reports-from-your-application.aspx